# Installing Nest Smoke Alarm against capped wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, nest, smoke-detectors

[image: Old capped wires that weren’t connected to anything.]

We moved in to a new home and the prior homeowner capped the old smoke alarm wires and replaced the old wired alarm with a battery unit that wasn’t wired up at all.

The nest smoke alarm has a 120V connection with a black and white wire that I can splice on to this. Before I do anything like that I wanted to ask.

I notice the old wires have two extra snipped wires (black and red) that are disconnected and not capped. It has a green wire spliced into a red wire that’s capped and goes nowhere. And it has a yellow wire similarly spliced.

This may have been a ceiling fan connection or it may have been a smoke detector hookup but I have no idea.

Advice appreciated!

Comment: That's "telephone" wire not electrical. It isn't robust enough for powering a fan.

Comment: Why is telephone wire in the ceiling like this by the smoke alarm? I guess is that enough for 120v? I'm definitely confused about this wiring and how the nest is supposed to hook up to it if at all.

Comment: No. Not good for 120V. The previous smoke alarm must have been a low voltage (12V DC) or similar. You can't use those wires for a Nest which, I believe, needs 120 VAC.

Comment: Can you trace those existing wires to where they go?

Comment: Those may have been for an interconnect between alarms, too. If one goes off it signals the rest and they all go off, waking up the whole house.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use those wires. They're likely left over from a 12V DC alarm system. The Nest smoke detectors require 120V AC which those wires are not capable of supplying. You'll need to figure out a different power source.